# How to export .csv from a directory based data-base sorted by date?

Tags: r, database, export, shiny

First time shiny user and I think I have most of this set up. The code i have retrieves certain data from a directory based database. the output is a csv file which i would like to be able to download directly from shiny.

What the code bellow does is pretty basic:

1. it takes `inputed` date and separates the D/M/Y and creates search terms
2. Certain keywords representing different files are also created for searching
3. It searches through a specific folder and retrieves a CSV. file
4. It then retrieves only data labeled as one of the `inputs` from this file
5. This data should be downloadable/ `ouptuted` through Shiny app in CSV or XLS format

My inputs are:

`inputId = "NaVDate"` = this is the date (used to search and retrieve .csv)

`inputId = "FundID"`    = This is the ID via which data is sorted in step 4

And output is are:

```
Forwards_Fund
```

These have already been included in the code bellow:

**UI.R**

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(

  # Date input by user
  dateInput(inputId = "NaVDate", label = "Select NaV Date", 
            format = "yyyy-mm-dd", startview = "month", weekstart = 0),
  # 
  textInput(inputId = "FundID", label = "Enter Fund ID (Numeric Only)", value = "", width = NULL, placeholder = NULL),

   downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")


)
```

**SERVER.R**

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  # extract inputed month / year / day and vectorize ( inputed in YYYY-MM-DD format)


  timestrip   <- reactive({unlist(strsplit(as.character(input$NaVDate), split = ""))}) 


  year   <- paste(timestrip[1], timestrip[2], timestrip[3], timestrip[4], sep = "")
  month  <- paste(timestrip[6], timestrip[7], sep = "")
  day    <- paste(timestrip[9], timestrip[10], sep = "")

  Date      = paste(year, month, day, sep = "")


  # create directory search criteria for the required files - eg.("XCP4P487FOFFET_20160315.CSV")

  Forwards  = paste0("*FOFFET_", Date, ".CSV$")


  # create main directory file path

  file_path <- paste0("C:/Users/dell Optiplex/Desktop/Equilibrium Weekly Macro/", year,"/", month) 


  # Search through file_path for criteria and create individual .csv filepath

  Forwards_CSV_path  = list.files(file_path, 
                                  pattern = Forwards, full.names=TRUE, 
                                  ignore.case=TRUE)


  # Read Data from CSV files

  Forwards_data = do.call(rbind, lapply(Forwards_CSV_path, function(x) read.csv(x, sep = ";", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))


  # Extract data from the inputed fund code (input$FundID) 

  Forwards_Fund  <- reactive({
    Forwards_data[which(Forwards_data$Fund.Code == input$FundID),]
  })

  ## download above data from shiny app

output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('data-', Sys.Date(), '.csv', sep='')
    },
    content = function(con) {
      write.csv(Forwards_Fund(), con)
    }
  )


}

shinyApp(server = server, ui = ui)
```

**ERROR**

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6132
Warning: Error in [: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
Stack trace (innermost first):
    44: paste
    43: server [#9]
     4: <Anonymous>
     3: do.call
     2: print.shiny.appobj
     1: print
Error in timestrip[1] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

**EDITS:**  - **UPDATE**

This is a shiny app which retrieves the name of a CSV file from a directory based database. I will continue to upgrade it with a download button.

I have a file on my desktop called EquilibriumWeeklyMacro

```
C:/Users/dell Optiplex/Desktop/EquilibriumWeeklyMacro/
```

It contains multiple files all sorted by date

```
C:/Users/dell Optiplex/Desktop/EquilibriumWeeklyMacro/2016/03/
```

In there i have a CSV file called

```
XCP4P487FOFFET_20160315.CSV
```

Note the `FOFFET_`  and `20160315` ending

The following Shiny app should be able to retrieve `XCP4P487FOFFET_20160315.CSV` from that file if i input `2016-03-15` in the Shiny app box.

The code bellow works except for the last part:

```
output$ForwardText  =  renderText({list.files(as.character(FileDirectory()), 
                                                     pattern = as.character(ForwardSearchString()), full.names=TRUE, 
                                                     ignore.case=TRUE)
                                                      })
```

I know that the problem lies in the above. 
Here is the code for the app :

```
library(shiny)


# XCP4P487FOFFET_20160315.CSV
# C:/Users/dell Optiplex/Desktop/EquilibriumWeeklyMacro/2016/03/

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Date input by user

  dateInput(inputId = "NaVDate", label = "Select NaV Date",
            format = "yyyy-mm-dd", startview = "month", weekstart = 0),

  textOutput("ForwardText")

)



  server <- function(input, output) {



    DateInput <-       reactive({format(as.Date(input$NaVDate), "%Y%m%d")})


    FileDirectory <- reactive({paste("C:/Users/dell Optiplex/Desktop/EquilibriumWeeklyMacro/",
                                     substr(as.character(DateInput()), 1, 4), "/",
                                     substr(as.character(DateInput()), 5, 6),"/", sep = "") 
                                      })
    # Search String 

    ForwardSearchString <- reactive({paste("FOFFET_", as.character(DateInput()), ".CSV")})

    # Search through file_path for criteria and create individual .csv filepath


   output$ForwardText  =  renderText({list.files(as.character(FileDirectory()), 
                                                 pattern = as.character(ForwardSearchString()), full.names=TRUE, 
                                                 ignore.case=TRUE)
                                                  })

  }

shinyApp(server = server, ui = ui)
```

Comment: What is wrong with `write.csv`? Or what exactly do you mean by "download".

Comment: write.csv would work, however this shiny app would be used by someone who is not familiar with R. I'll need a clickable button in my shiny app which would export the 6 csv files.

Comment: This is not really related to `database`. Maybe `data.frame`

Answer (score 2):

Shiny has a widget for this called a `downloadButton`, documentation can be found [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/downloadButton.html).

I've integrated into your app:

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(

  # Date input by user
  dateInput(inputId = "NaVDate", label = "Select NaV Date", 
            format = "yyyy-mm-dd", startview = "month", weekstart = 0),
  # 
  textInput(inputId = "FundID", label = "Enter Fund ID (Numeric Only)", value = "", width = NULL, placeholder = NULL),

  downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")

)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # extract inputed month / year / day and vectorize ( inputed in YYYY-MM-DD format)


  timestrip   <- reactive({unlist(strsplit(as.character(input$NaVDate), split = ""))}) 

  Forwards_Fund  <- reactive({
    year   <- paste(timestrip()[1], timestrip()[2], timestrip()[3], timestrip()[4], sep = "")
    month  <- paste(timestrip()[6], timestrip()[7], sep = "")
    day    <- paste(timestrip()[9], timestrip()[10], sep = "")

    Date      = paste(year, month, day, sep = "")


    # create directory search criteria for the required files - eg.("XCP4P487FOFFET_20160315.CSV")

    Forwards  = paste0("*FOFFET_", Date, ".CSV$")


    # create main directory file path

    file_path <- paste0("C:/Users/dell Optiplex/Desktop/Equilibrium Weekly Macro/", year,"/", month) 


    # Search through file_path for criteria and create individual .csv filepath

    Forwards_CSV_path  = list.files(file_path, 
                                  pattern = Forwards, full.names=TRUE, 
                                  ignore.case=TRUE)


    # Read Data from CSV files

    Forwards_data = do.call(rbind, lapply(Forwards_CSV_path, function(x) read.csv(x, sep = ";", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))


    # Extract data from the inputed fund code (input$FundID) 


    Forwards_data[which(Forwards_data$Fund.Code == input$FundID),]
  })

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('data-', Sys.Date(), '.csv', sep='')
    },
    content = function(con) {
      write.csv(Forwards_Fund(), con)
    }
  )

}

shinyApp(server = server, ui = ui)
```

Comment: i get this error: 
`Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6132
Warning: Error in [: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
Stack trace (innermost first):
    44: paste
    43: server [#9]
     4: <Anonymous>
     3: do.call
     2: print.shiny.appobj
     1: print
Error in timestrip[1] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable` do you think i have used the `reactive` function and the `input$FundID/ input$NaVDate` correctly above?

Comment: Nice, I have never used the `downloadButton` myself, will give it a try.

Comment: @AlexBădoi yes, it looks like you are using reactive expressions incorrectly, please see my edits.

Comment: mkemp it looks like you removed the `Forwards_Fund` vector so the output going into your `output$downloadData` doesn't actually exist in the code any more. Also there are some extra brackets left over `})` . I'm not sure if this is entirely correct.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample program with an action button that only writes a csv when it is clicked on. Not going to integrate it in your program because your program is too big and I don't have your data, but you should be able to work with this:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
u <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Simple Shiny Input"),

  sidebarLayout(position = "left",
                sidebarPanel( 
                              actionButton("savebutton", "Save Data"),
                              sliderInput("cnt","Count:",100,1000,500,5)
                ),
                mainPanel(plotOutput('stdplot'))
  )
))
s <- shinyServer(function(input, output) 
{
  histdata <- reactive({
      set.seed(1234)
      df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(input$cnt))
    } )
  output$stdplot = renderPlot({
      qplot(data=histdata(),x,fill=I("blue"),bins=30)
    })
  savedata <- observe({ 
        input$savebutton
        if (input$savebutton>0){
           write.csv(histdata(),"histo.csv")
        }
      })
  })
shinyApp(ui=u,server=s)
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi Mike, i appreciate you for your answer. although helpful, your save data code is relative to the size of one of your inputs. I'm not sure it's exactly what i need. Come back in a day or 2 and if you have time i'll put a bounty on this. It is a long program but everything was done 6 times. I have shortened my code to only include 1 variable rather than 6.

Comment: No problem, although I am not sure what your statement "our save data code is relative to the size of one of your inputs" means. Guessing, I would say you mean the dependency of `histdata` on `input$cnt`. However that is incidental, the point of the example is sole to illustrate how an `actionButton` can be used to trigger the saving of a data frame (or several).